# Apply jQuery function to one element and *NOT* its descendants

Tags: jquery

I want to add certain classes to the various levels of my websites nav header. So I'll have something in the end like

```
$('#navCol > ul > li > ul > li > ul').addClass('lvl2');
    // Each ‘li > ul’ past the first ‘ul’ indicates another sub-level.
```

to add the `lvl2` class to the second level, etc. Having said that, not only does it apply said class to the second level, it also adds it to the other `ul`s beneath it. Is there a way to specify that I only want to include the element and not its descendants.

Comment: Did you mean "it also adds it to the other uls **next to** it"?

Comment: your selector will apply only to the third `ul`. it will never added to other `ul`s beneath it.

Comment: Yeah, the problem was when I was using a for loop and I forgot to add a `>` in there somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like

```
$('#navCol > ul > li > ul > li').children("ul").each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('lvl2');
});
```

or if you just want the first url, try something like

```
$('#navCol > ul > li > ul > li').children("ul:first").each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('lvl2');
});
```

Comment: I think the `.each` is unnecessary. You can shorten the statement to just used `.addClass` following the `children("ul")` or `children("ul:first")` calls.

Comment: Oh! I realized what I did wrong. What I said in the question is valid and works. I was using a `for` loop to loop through adding ` li > ul` multiple times to `#navCol > ul`, but I forgot the extra `>` before the `li`, so that's why it didn't work. Chris' answer works, too, but the code I included in the question is valid and behaves correctly.

Comment: I think you are right. I think jQuery will automatically iterate when it finds multiple elements. Good Call!